# Android Camera 2 close Daemon Warning

Tags: android, multithreading, android-camera, android-service

Does someone know about how to prevent android camera 2 close daemon warning :

```
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {37798789} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {37798789} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(Handler.java:623)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.quit(RequestThreadManager.java:941)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.close(LegacyCameraDevice.java:444)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.finalize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:468)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:209)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:192)
11-18 22:49:26.330 32353-32365/zpavel.com.myapplication W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I'm testing it on Galaxy A5, android 5.0.2, api level 21, through a service which opens and stops camera every laps of time. Everything seems to work well excerpt this warning which is still annoying.

Is it possible to stop the daemon at the same time as camera closes and prevent this warning to appear?

Thanks in advance for your help.